# Mysql: use join table column value in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

`catalog_product_entity` table

[image]

`catalog_product_relation` table

[image]

`catalog_product_entity_varchar` table

[image]

I want to export the sku and  url from above tables:

- `sku` is in `catalog_product_entity` table.
- `url` is in `catalog_product_relation` table.

I tried to join this three tables and select the url values if catalog_product_entity tables entity_id matches with the `child_id` column in `catalog_product_relation` then use the parent_id in where clause other wise use entity_id;

```
select  cpe.sku
,       value 
from    catalog_product_entity as cpe
left join 
        catalog_product_entity_varchar as cpev
on      cpe.entity_id = cpev.entity_id
where   cpev.attribute_id = 119 and 
        type_id = "simple" and 
        cpev.store_id=0 and 
        cpev.entity_id = 
        (
        select  parent_id
        from    catalog_product_relation 
        where   child_id = cpe.entity_id
        )
```

Above query is not the correct query i uploaded here for understanding

**Edit:**

catalog_product_entity_varchar taables header

[image]

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking of people. Show desired output, and explain what the current query produces and why that is wrong.

Comment: what are the column headings in catalog_product_entity? you're joining on entity_id but which column in the in the join table. Also you filter looks abit convoluted - are you sure there is a record that matches?

Comment: Move the cpev conditions from WHERE to ON to get true left join result.

Comment: Please post the `CREATE TABLE` statements, and the foreign keys. We can't guess about your table structures.

Comment: @dbajtr I have edit the question please check.

Comment: Without the filter (`WHERE`) the query looks fine. If you arn't getting expected results i would double check that a record exists first by applying the logic one step at a time

Comment: column type_id doesn't belong to catalog_product_entity_varchar table. it must be in another table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `join` the value twice, once directly, and once through the intermediate parent-child table.  Use `coalesce` to fall back to the child value when the parent value is not found:

```
select  cpe.sku
,       coalesce(parent_cpev.value, child_cpev.value)
from    catalog_product_entity as cpe
left join 
        catalog_product_entity_varchar as child_cpev
on      child_cpev.entity_id = cpe.entity_id
        and child_cpev.attribute_id = 119
        and child_cpev.store_id = 0
left join
        catalog_product_relation as cpr
on      cpe.entity_id = cpr.child_id
left join 
        catalog_product_entity_varchar as parent_cpev
on      parent_cpev.entity_id = cpr.parent_id
        and parent_cpev.attribute_id = 119
        and parent_cpev.store_id = 0
where   cpe.type_id = 'simple'
```

Comment: Thanks. will try this query

Comment: I tried edited query but it is giving `Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'child_cpev.type_id' in 'on clause' ` error.

Comment: Might have been the double quotes, a SQL string literal belongs in single quotes

Comment: If the `type_id` column is in the `catalog_product_entity` table, the condition should be in the `where` clause. I hope the answer points you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

type_id column doesn't have (missing) table alias prefix specified in your query.